# ko.JSON with observableArray throws Uncaught DOMException

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm trying to persist an observable array to localStorage. To do this I'm using ko.toJSON.

```
var that = this;
this.items = ko.observableArray();
this.items.subscribe(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("items", ko.toJSON(that.items()));
});
```

All that gets persisted to localStorage is `false`.

It throws a very random looking error: `knockout-3.4.2.js:55 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules`.

Any idea what's going on here?

I get the error as well with a simple `var json = ko.toJSON(that.items());` so it clearly comes from that. However, I do not get that error when simply doing this: `var json = ko.toJSON([{'key': 'value'}]);`.

**UPDATE: Here's the full error message:**

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 
'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
at http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:55:405
at c (http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:56:172)
at b (http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:55:380)
at http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:56:23
at c (http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:56:172)
at b (http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:55:380)
at http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:56:23
at c (http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:56:172)
at b (http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:55:380)
at http://localhost:8080/js/knockout-3.4.2.js:56:23
```

**UPDATE2: Here's the actual section of code where the problem lies:**

This is the exact context of the problem:

```
    this.savedPlaces.subscribe(function() {
    // Add all places to filteredPlaces
    that.filterPlaces();
    // Reinitialize the filter
    that.filterString("");
    // Update the markers
    that.updateMarkers();
    // Store itself in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("savedPlaces", ko.toJSON(that.savedPlaces()));
});
```

When I comment out that last line, I get no issue.

I also get no issue if I replace it with: `localStorage.setItem("savedPlaces", ko.toJSON([{item: "item"}]));`

I tried to give an example of content for `items` but apparently observableArrays are deep (recursive) objects, making it impossible for me to copy paste for the DevTools console on Chrome. However it looks something like:

```
[{'marker': a_google_maps_marker_object,
  'place': {data: mostly strings...}]
```

Comment: Is `items` also bound to the view? I can't imagine `ko.toJSON` being the cause of this error...

Comment: The code looks fine so far. Is `cssRules` a property in each `item` in the array? What is `CSSStyleSheet`? Can you show more of the relevant code?

Comment: Actually apparently I don't use `items` in the view so I guess I could actually simply store it as a regular array, which would likely solve my problem! But I still don't understand why I get that issue!
cssRules and CSSStyleSheet have nothing to do with my code...

I'll update the original post to include the full error.

Comment: Second earlier comments. The problem is going to be in code that we can't see in this question. Please try to create an [mcve] from your actual codebase, if possible.

Comment: Thing is I just don't see what else could be relevant. I'll edit the post again, trying to include more details.

Comment: Ok I got the issue. Still don't understand why it throws that specific error but I at least get why it throws _an_ error... My observable array is recursive so it can't convert it to json (I tried with making it a regular array then using `JSON.stringify` on it and that didn't work either). It comes from the Google Maps marker object that I store in it. So I'll try to fix my Array so it can be converted properly. If that works I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue.
My observable array contained a Google Maps marker. These are recursive arrays, which cannot be JSONified.

I removed the Google Maps marker from my array and everything was fine.

Still strange though that Knockout throws this cryptic error.